# How can i clear validation field pop ups with an OnClick on the form reset button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i am using a live validation script on a form and when a field is correctly filled a pop up displays.

i am trying to clear these pop ups with the form reset button, the reset button will clear all the field inputs but the javascript pop up remains.

Script used - http://livevalidation.com/

JSFiddle that shows the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/adamskee/e5qQQ/

thanks ;-)

```
    <form id="form_email_348177" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

    <div class="formwrapper">

    <h3>1. Enter your contact details here</h3>

    <div class="questio">
    <div class="formquest">Your Name*</div>
    <div class="formextras">Add your First and Surname</div>
    </div>
    <div class="forminput"><input type="text" name="q348177:q1" value="" size="30" maxlength="300"  id="q348177_q1" class="sq-form-field" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var q348177_q1 = new LiveValidation('q348177_q1');
    q348177_q1.add(Validate.Presence);
    </script>  
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="questio">
    <div class="formquest">Company Name*</div>
    <div class="formextras">Add your Company Name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="forminput"><input type="text" name="q348177:q2" value="" size="30" maxlength="300"  id="q348177_q2" class="sq-form-field" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var q348177_q2 = new LiveValidation('q348177_q2');
    q348177_q2.add(Validate.Presence);
    </script> 
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="questio">
    <div class="formquest">Company Address*</div>
    <div class="formextras">Postal Address</div>
    </div>
    <div class="forminput"><input type="text" name="q348177:q3" value="" size="30" maxlength="300"  id="q348177_q3" class="sq-form-field" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var q348177_q3 = new LiveValidation('q348177_q3');
    q348177_q3.add(Validate.Presence);
    </script> 
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="form_email_348177_submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton" id="form_email_348177_submit" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" />  
    <input type="reset" name="form_email_348177_reset" value="Reset" class="resetbutton" id="form_email_348177_reset" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: There seems to be some problem in your JSFiddle

Comment: sorry, fixed it..http://jsfiddle.net/adamskee/e5qQQ/

Comment: did it the easy way and added an Onclick event to the RESET button that relaods the page. Not what i wanted to do but was successful in clearing the popups.